# Limit HttpWebRequest request&response sizes

Tags: .net, httpwebrequest, limit, webclient, httpwebresponse

Is there a way to limit request\response sizes for HttpWebRequest, WebClient, HttpClient and other ways to communicate with network?

I know that we can set concurrency limit [ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and maximum size of request for Asp.Net applications by [maxRequestLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.maxrequestlength%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) value in web.config but second one is just for web applications.

Is there a way to limit it in usual **Desktop** application?